# Casting a pointer does not produce an lvalue. Why?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, lvalue

After posting one of my most controversial answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444464/read-bytes-methods-in-c-c/7444502#7444502), I dare to ask a few questions and eventually fill some gaps in my knowledge.

Why isn't an expression of the kind `((type_t *) x)` considered a valid lvalue, assuming that `x` itself is a pointer and an lvalue, not just some expression?

I know many will say "the standard disallows it", but from a logical standpoint it seems reasonable. What is the reason that the standard disallows it? After all, any two pointers are of the same size and the pointer type is just a compile-time abstraction that indicates the appropriate offset that should be applied when doing pointer arithmetic.

Comment: I think, that already "any two pointers are of the same size" is wrong. Not sure, but I think this is actually architecture dependent. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241205/are-all-data-pointers-of-the-same-size-in-one-platform/1241314#1241314

Comment: Standard C guarantees that pointers to objects are all the same size, but allows pointers to functions to be of different sizes (from each other and from pointers to objects).  POSIX requires pointers to objects to be the same size as pointers to functions.

Comment: I don't see why you'd have any need to cast an lvalue. In an assignment, you can cast the rvalue being assigned. When getting a pointer, you can cast the pointer. By the way, casts don't always result in something the same size (`int` ⇒ `char`, for example).

Comment: @Jonathan: read 6.2.5/27 in [n1256.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf): "... Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements."

Comment: I misspoke. ISO 9899:1999 §6.2.5¶26 says: _A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements._

Comment: FWIW, the POSIX 2008 standard says (System Interfaces, §2.12.3 Pointer Types):

_All function pointer types shall have the same representation as the type pointer to void. Conversion of a function pointer to `void *` shall not alter the representation. A `void *` value resulting from such a conversion can be converted back to the original function pointer type, using an explicit cast, without loss of information.

Note:
    The ISO C standard does not require this, but it is required for POSIX conformance._

Comment: Your logic is wrong. See John Bode's answer and my comment on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An even better example, unary `+` yields an rvalue, as does `x+0`.

The underlying reason is that all these things, including your cast, create a new value. Casting a value to the type it already is, likewise creates a new value, never mind whether pointers to different types have the same representation or not. In some cases, the new value happens to be equal to the old value, but in principle it's a new value, it's not intended to be used as a reference to the old object, and that's why it's an rvalue.

For these to be lvalues, the standard would have to add some special cases that certain operations when used on an lvalue result in a reference to the old object, instead of a new value. AFAIK there's no great demand for those special cases.

Comment: sir I don't understand how unary plus (+a) yields rvalue,If it yields rvalue then there should be lvalue required error for this (+a)++; 
but it is working.....plz explain it
thnks

Answer (score 8):

The result of a cast is never an lvalue by itself. But `*((type_t *) x)` is an lvalue.

Comment: But `((type *)x)` is not an lvalue, so `*((type *)x)++` fails.

Answer (score 4):

Because cast expressions *in general* do not yield lvalues.

Comment: This is the best answer of all. People who expect `(type *)foo` to be an lvalue usually have a misunderstanding of C and think that casts are *reinterpretations of bits*. This is wrong. A cast is an operation on values, and as such, the lvalue is "gone" even "before the cast takes place", as the input operand to the cast is the value of an expression (sometimes called an rvalue), not an lvalue.

Comment: @R.., "value or an expressions" and rvalue does not mean the same thing since expressions can evaluate to lvalues too.

Comment: Of, not or. In the phrase "Value of an expression", the key word is **value**. See the footnote in 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators.

Answer (score 2):

Well, casting performs a type conversion. In general case type conversion is a non-trivial operation, which completely changes the representation of the value. Under these circumstances it should be painfully obvious that the result of any conversion is cannot possibly be an lvalue.

For example, if you have an `int i = 0;`  variable, you can convert it to type `double` as `(double) i`. How can you possibly expect the result of this conversion to be an lvalue? I mean, it just doesn't make any sense. You apparently expect to be able to do `(double) i = 3.0;`... Or `double *p = &(double) i;` So, what should happen to the value of `i` in the former example, considering that type `double` might not even have the same size as type `int`? And even if they had the same size, what would you expect to happen?

Your assumption about all pointers having the same size is incorrect. In C language in general case (with few exceptions) different pointer types have different sizes, different internal representations and different alignment requirements. Even if they were guaranteed to have the same representation, I still don't see why pointers should be separated from all other types and given special treatment in explicit cast situations.

Finally, what you seem to be advocating here is that your original conversion should perform a raw-memory reinterpretation of one pointer type as another pointer type. Raw-memory reinterpretation in almost all cases is a hack. Why this hack should be elevated to the level of the language feature is entirely not clear to me.

Since it is a hack, performing such reinterpretations should require a conscious effort from the user. If you want to perform it in your example, you should do `*(type_t **) &x`, which will indeed reinterpret `x` as an lvalue of type `type_t *`. But allowing the same thing through a mere `(type_t *) x` would be a disaster completely disconnected with the design principles of C language.

Comment: From the code the questioner refers to in the question, what he actually wants is to abbreviate `p = (int*)p + 1`, where `p` has type `void*`, to `((int*)p)++`. It's not clear to me whether this is an attempt to argue that the standard should allow that, or just to correct the misunderstanding that led the questioner to think the latter would work...

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are right and wrong at the same time.

In C there is an ability to safely typecast any lvalue to any lvalue. However, the syntax is a bit different than your straight forward approach:

**lvalue pointers can be casted to lvalue pointers of a different type** like this in C:

```
char *ptr;

ptr = malloc(20);
assert(ptr);
*(*(int **)&ptr)++ = 5;
```

As `malloc()` is required to fulfill all alignment requirements, this also is an acceptable use.  However, following is not portable and may lead to an exception due to wrong alignment on certain machines:

```
char *ptr;

ptr = malloc(20);
assert(ptr);
*ptr++ = 0;
*(*(int **)&ptr)++ = 5;  /* can throw an exception due to misalignment */
```

To sum it up:

- If you cast a pointer, this leads to an rvalue.
- Using `*` on a pointer leads to an lvalue (`*ptr` can be assigned to).
- `++` (like in `*(arg)++`) needs an lvalue to operate on (`arg` must be an lvalue)

Hence `((int *)ptr)++` fails, because `ptr` is an lvalue, but `(int *)ptr` is not.  The `++` can be rewritten as `((int *)ptr += 1, ptr-1)`, and it's the `(int *)ptr += 1` which fails due to the cast resulting in a pure rvalue.

---

Please note that it is not a language shortcoming.   Casting must not produce lvalues.  Look at following:

```
(double *)1   = 0;
(double)ptr   = 0;
(double)1     = 0;
(double *)ptr = 0;
```

The first 3 do not compile.  Why would anybody expect the 4th line to compile?  Programming languages should never expose such surprising behavior.  Even more, this may lead to some unclear behavior of programs.  Consider:

```
#ifndef DATA
#define DATA double
#endif
#define DATA_CAST(X) ((DATA)(X))

DATA_CAST(ptr) = 3;
```

This cannot compile, right?  However if your expectation helds, this suddenly compiles with `cc -DDATA='double *'`!  From a stability point of view it is important not to introduces such contextual lvalues for certain casts.

The right thing for C is that there are either lvalues or there are not, and this shall not depend on some arbitrary context which might be surprising.

---

As [noted by Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7446788) there already is one operator to create lvalues.  It's the pointer dereferencing operator, the "unary `*`" (as in `*ptr`).

Note that `*ptr` can be written as `0[ptr]` and `*ptr++` can be written as `0[ptr++]`.  Array subscripts are lvalues, so `*ptr` is an lvalue, too.

Wait, what?  `0[ptr]` must be an error, right?

Actually, no.  Try it!  This is valid C.  Following C program is valid on Intel 32/64 bit in all respects, so it compiles and runs successfully:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int
main()
{
  char *ptr;

  ptr = malloc(20);
  assert(ptr);

  0[(*(int **)&ptr)++] = 5;
  assert(ptr[-1]==0 && ptr[-2]==0 && ptr[-3]==0 && ptr[-4]==5);

  return 0;
}
```

---

In C we can have it both.  Casts, which never create lvalues.  And the ability to use casts in a way, that we can keep the lvalue property alive.

But to get an lvalue out of casting, two more steps are needed:

- Before the cast, get the address of the original lvalue.  As it is an lvalue, you always can get this address.
- Cast to the pointer of the desired type (usually the desired type is a pointer as well, so you have a pointer to that pointer).
- After the cast, dereference this additional pointer, which gives you an lvalue again.

Hence instead of the wrong `*((int *)ptr)++` we can write `*(*(int **)&ptr)++`.  This also makes sure, that `ptr` in this expression must be an lvalue already.  Or to write this with the help of the C Preprocessor:

```
#define LVALUE_CAST(TYPE,PTR) (*((TYPE *)&(PTR)))
```

So for any passed in `void *ptr` (which might disguises as `char *ptr`), we can write:

```
*LVALUE_CAST(int *,ptr)++ = 5;
```

Except the usual pointer arithmetic caveats (abnormal program termination or undefined behavior on incompatible types, which mostly stems from aligment issues), this is proper C.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard was written to support exotic machine architectures that require weird hacks to implement the C pointer model for all pointed-to types. In order to allow the compiler to use the most efficient pointer representation for each pointed-to type, the C standard does not require different pointer representations to be compatible.  On such an exotic architecture the void pointer type must use the most general and thus slowest of the different representations.  There are some specific examples of such now obsolete architectures in the C FAQ: http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that if `x` is a pointer type, `*(type_t **)&x` is an lvalue. However, accessing it as such except perhaps in very restricted circumstances invokes undefined behavior due to aliasing violations. The only time it *might* be legal is if the pointer types are corresponding signed/unsigned or void/char pointer types, but even then I'm doubtful.

`(type_t *)x` is not an lvalue, because `(T)x` is never an lvalue, regardless of the type `T` or the expression `x`. `(type_t *)` is just a special case of `(T)`.

Answer (score 1):

From a top level, it would generally serve no purpose. Instead of '((type_t *) x) = ' one might as well go ahead and do 'x = ', assuming x is a pointer in your example. If one wishes to directly modify values pointed by the address 'x' but at the same time after interpreting it to be a pointer to a new data type then *((type_t **) &x) =  is the way forward. Again ((type_t **) &x) =  would serve no purpose, let alone the fact it is not a valid lvalue.

Also in cases of ((int *)x)++, where at least 'gcc' does not complain along the lines of 'lvalue' it could be reinterpreting it as 'x = (int *)x + 1'