# C Casts Inside a Macro

Tags: c, macros, casting, lvalue

I am trying to implement the standard [xor swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm) algorithm as a C macro.

I have two versions of the macro. One that doesn't worry about the types and one that attempts to cast everything to an integer.

Here are the macro's

```
#define XOR_SWAP(a,b) ((a)^=(b),(b)^=(a),(a)^=(b))

#define LVALUE_CAST(type,value) (*((type)*)&(value))
#define XOR_CAST_SWAP(type,a,b) (LVALUE_CAST((type),(a))=(type)(a)^(type)(b),LVALUE_CAST((type),(b))=(type)(b)^(type)(a),LVALUE_CAST((type),(a))=(type)(a)^(type)(b))
```

I know it's a pain to read the one with a cast, but your efforts are appreciated.

The error that I'm getting is:

```
some_file.c(260,3): expected expression before ')' token
```

Now, I'm looking at it but I still can't figure out where my problem lies.

I've even used the `-save-temps` option to capture the preprocessor output and the line looks like this:

```
((*(((intptr_t))*)&((Block1)))=(intptr_t)(Block1)^(intptr_t)(Block2),(*(((intptr_t))*)&((Block2)))=(intptr_t)(Block2)^(intptr_t)(Block1),(*(((intptr_t))*)&((Block1)))=(intptr_t)(Block1)^(intptr_t)(Block2));
```

Before anybody mentions it, I've since realized that I should probably make this a function instead of a macro. Or even better, just use that extra variable to do the swap, it isn't hard.

But I want to know why this macro doesn't work. The brackets seem to match exactly as I wanted them to, so why is it complaining?

The `LVALUE_CAST` is something I took from @Jens Gustedt's answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446489/casting-a-pointer-does-not-produce-an-lvalue-why/7446788#7446788) SO question.

**Update:**

The macro call that produces that preprocessor output looks like this:

```
XOR_CAST_SWAP(intptr_t, Block1, Block2);
```

Comment: Is this just for fun?  Using the xor swap (especially hidden behind a macro, and with all these casts) is a pretty bad idea...  (UPDATE: just noticed you wrote a disclaimer...)

Comment: Yup, it's just to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: What does the macro call look like, which produced that output?

Comment: It looks like `XOR_CAST_SWAP(intptr_t, Block1, Block2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can wrap types in arbitrary levels of parentheses.<sup>*</sup>  So this compiles fine:

```
((*(intptr_t*)&((Block1)))=(intptr_t)(Block1)^(intptr_t)(Block2),(*(intptr_t*)&((Block2)))=(intptr_t)(Block2)^(intptr_t)(Block1),(*(intptr_t*)&((Block1)))=(intptr_t)(Block1)^(intptr_t)(Block2));
```

---

<sub>* Disclaimer: this is purely empirical!  I don't intend to peruse the standard to figure out what the details are...</sub>

Comment: You are correct, removing them did fix my issue. Thanks. I'm accepting the answer, but can I ask if you know of the actual reason why parenthesis have this effect on types?

Comment: @nonsensical: I guess it's just the grammar of the C language that dictates this.

Comment: @nonsensical Yep, parens simply don't appear for the grammar for *type-specifier* which is what `int` is, and is required by a *cast-expression*. The only place unlimited nesting is allowed in there appears to be around abstract-declarators, e.g. `(int(((((*)))))(void)) foo` casts to pointer to function type.

Comment: @Potatoswatter You're right. I was just looking up the grammar myself at http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~mckeeman/cs48/references/c.html and found the same, but I think that regular declarators also allow infinite parens.

Comment: @nonsensical Yes, but a regular declarator can't go inside a cast-expression.