# Need help compiling c program using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, freebsd

I am running FreeBSD 9.2, attempting to compile Dalnet ircd df4.6.5.

I am running into this error, and do not understand it.

```
channel.c:2536: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Which is this line of code:

```
lopt->next = (LOpts *)lopt->yeslist=lopt->nolist=(Link *)NULL;
```

All of the previous answers to this error I have found was when someone has used = instead of == in an if statement, I know that this code compiles on earlier versions of FreeBSD, but I do not understand what it is doing in the first place to attempt to fix it.

Thank you.

Comment: What do all those casts do?

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446489/casting-a-pointer-does-not-produce-an-lvalue-why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(LOpts *)lopt->yeslist` is not an lvalue. Hence the compiler error.

Change the line to:

```
lopt->yeslist=lopt->nolist=(Link *)NULL;
lopt->next = (LOpts *)NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you, I still have no idea whats going on here, but it works.

Comment: @bolwire, You can take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category to get a quick idea of what an `lvalue` is.