# What does *(DWORD_PTR*)&functionA = functionB( var1, var2); do?

Tags: c, winapi, casting, function-pointers

```
*(DWORD_PTR*)&FunctionA =  FunctionB( var1, var2, etc...);
```

What does this code mean? What does it do?

I tried to search Google, but I didn't know what terms to use.

Previously in the code there is:

```
BOOL (WINAPI * FunctionA) (var1, var2, etc...) = NULL;
```

Which identifies what "FunctionA" is.

Comment: Seems like it assigns pointer to some function to variable `functionA`. `functionB` may be [`GetWindowLong() / GetWindowLongPtr()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584(v=vs.85).aspx) or something similar, that has integral return type but actually may return function pointer.

Comment: it's technically undefined behavior... so it could do well... anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ugly code, that's what it is.

What it's *basically* doing is calling a function (`FunctionB`) that returns a pointer to another function, and assigning that pointer to the variable `FunctionA`. Now, if that was all that was going on, then the code would look very simple:

```
FunctionA = FunctionB( var1, var2, etc... );
```

Unfortunately, for some weird reason (that presumably made a lot of sense to whoever originally designed that API), the return type of `FunctionB` is *not* declared to be a function pointer, but rather a `DWORD_PTR` (an integer type that matches the size of a pointer on the underlying platform). That means that the return value of `FunctionB` cannot be directly assigned to the variable `FunctionA`, but has to be cast into an actual function pointer first (which, as has been noted in the comments, is technically undefined behavior according to the C standard, although e.g. POSIX does define semantics for it).

Now, if the type of the `FunctionA` variable was something simple, like, say `my_func_ptr_t`, then this would still be easy to write:

```
FunctionA = (my_func_ptr_t) FunctionB( var1, var2, etc... );
```

But alas, in your code `FunctionA` is declared as:

```
BOOL (WINAPI * FunctionA) (arg1, arg2, etc...) = NULL;
```

which means that its type is something like `BOOL (WINAPI *) (arg1, arg2, etc...)`, and so the cast would look like this:

```
FunctionA = (BOOL (WINAPI *) (arg1, arg2, etc...)) FunctionB( var1, var2, etc... );
```

It seems that whoever wrote that code decided that such a cast was too complicated, and instead came up with a trick: instead of casting the return value of `FunctionB` into a function pointer, wouldn't it be so much easier to cast `FunctionA` into a `DWORD_PTR`, like this:

```
(DWORD_PTR) FunctionA = FunctionB( var1, var2, etc... ); /* this doesn't work :( */
```

But of course, that won't compile; a cast just converts the *value* of a variable into another type, and you can't assign something to the converted value. (In technical terms, [a cast is not an lvalue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446489/casting-a-pointer-does-not-produce-an-lvalue-why)) But wait, you *can* assign to a dereferenced pointer! So if we...

1. take a pointer to `FunctionA` (which will thus be a pointer to a function pointer),
2. cast it into a pointer to a `DWORD_PTR`, and
3. dereference that pointer,

then we get a valid `DWORD_PTR` lvalue that we can assign to, and which just happens to share the same memory address as the variable `FunctionA`. Never mind that all this invokes undefined behavior six ways to Sunday according to the C standard — we know our compiler will handle it the way we expect, right?

So, this is precisely what the code does:

1. `&FunctionA` returns a pointer to the variable `FunctionA`,
2. `(DWORD_PTR *)` casts this pointer so that it now claims to point to a variable of type `DWORD_PTR`, and
3. the `*` on the left dereferences this pointer, so that the return value of `FunctionB` gets assigned to whatever memory location it points to (which, conveniently, just happens to be the location of `FunctionA`).

But of course, all this relies on the (non-standard) assumption that, on the particular compiler and platform this code is meant for, writing a `DWORD_PTR` into memory and then using that same memory location as a function pointer actually works and calls the expected function, as opposed to e.g triggering an access violation, jumping into the wrong address, or [making demons fly out of your nose.](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

---

OK, so it's ugly code. How would I do it better, then?

Well, ideally, I'd change `FunctionB` so that it would actually return a function pointer of the appropriate type, so that none of these casting shenanigans would be needed in the first place.

If that really wasn't possible for some reason (and I'd try pretty hard to *make* it possible, even redesigning the API if necessary), the next best solution would be explicitly casting the return value of `FunctionB`. Sure, it's undefined behavior, but at least it's explicit about what it tries to do.

Either way, I would definitely `typedef` the actual function pointer type into something more readable.  That way, the code (with an explicit cast) might end up looking something like this:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI * my_func_ptr_t) (arg1, arg2, etc...);
my_func_ptr_t FunctionA = NULL;
/* ... */
FunctionA = (my_func_ptr_t) FunctionB( var1, var2, etc... );
```

Comment: (Also putting it here.) For what it's worth, the C standard does not allow you to cast a pointer to data to a pointer to function. The trick here is the workaround [suggested by POSIX for users of its equivalent to `GetProcAddress()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html). I think some people mentioned the first part above, but here's the second part :/ The OP's snippet uses `DWORD_PTR` instead of `void *`; I'm not sure if that's less safe... (They are the same size.)

Comment: @andlabs: To be pedantic, while you're right that "the C standard does not allow you to cast a pointer to data to a pointer to function", AFAICT it doesn't expressly forbid it, either. It's simply undefined behavior, meaning that compilers are free to do anything if you try it, from issuing a warning to releasing nasal demons to just making it work as expected. Also, the "mandatory warning" note seems to have been a mistake in older editions of POSIX; [it has been removed from the 2013 edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html), along with the workaround.

Comment: `DWORD_PTR` is NOT a **pointer to a `DWORD`** (that would be `LPDWORD` instead).  A `DWORD_PTR` is a **pointer-sized DWORD** instead.  It is a 32bit number on 32bit systems, and a 64bit number on 64bit systems.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming it's the `*(DWORD_PTR*)&functionA` part that confuses you?

Lets break it down into parts. Lets begin with `&functionA`. It takes the address of `functionA` (whatever that is) and returns a pointer to it.

Then we have `(DWORD_PTR*)` which casts the pointer to `functionA` to a pointer to `DWORD_PTR`.

Lastly the the lone `*` at the beginning, which is the dereference operator, which takes a pointer and gives you the value of what if points to.

Put together with the function call, it simply assigns the result of calling `functionB` to the variable `functionA`.

I'm just guessing here, but it's possible that `functionB` returns a pointer to a function in some generic way (as a `DWORD_PTR` would be my guess) and then assign this to the variable `functionA` which probably have the type pointer to function. The casting and address-of and dereference operators are because the return type of `functionB`. ***I guess***. Without more information or context it's impossible to say anything for certain.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that casting a function pointer to a non-function pointer type **IS** undefined behavior, despite POSIX requiring it (and most compilers supporting it)

Comment: @Mgetz Yes, it is surely UB, but it is the fact that some systems widely use such manipulations even in their API (e.g. WinAPI).

Comment: @Serhio actually WIN32 is remarkably free of `void*` callbacks, POSIX is the only one that has them as far as I'm aware

Comment: "Lets break it down into parts. Lets begin with &functionA. It takes the address of functionA (whatever that is) and returns a pointer to it." isn't it (like variables) just that it returns an address? (which is what you mentioned) but not return a pointer (as that would require the asterisk)?

Comment: Also, "Put together with the function call, it simply assigns the result of calling functionB to functionA." What does it mean to assign a value to a function?

Comment: @w4j3d Say you have e.g. `int a;`. Then if you do `&a` you get a pointer to `a` and the result is of type `int*`.

Comment: @w4j3d `functionA` has to be a variable, added that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think it is a function (functionA), as previously in the code there is this: BOOL (WINAPI * functionA) (var1, var2, etc...) = NULL;

Comment: @w4j3d No that declares `functionA` as a pointer to a function, it's a variable that can point to any function taking the specified arguments and returning `BOOL`. That declaration is also crucial information that should have been in the question body. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've realized this only afterwards. Should I reask the question?

Comment: @w4j3d No. If you're not happy with my answer (that's okay) then keep on refining your question until you get an acceptable answer. Editing the question will put it back up on the front page for all to see.

Comment: OK!  if it's (functionA) a pointer to a function - which is assigned the value NULL at the beginning - shouldn't it be assigned "&functionB" and not "functionB"?

Comment: @w4j3d No, you *call* `functionB` to get a result, and it's the result of that call that is assigned to `functionA`.

Comment: @w4j3d That's what it seems like.

Comment: (Also putting it here.) For what it's worth, the C standard does not allow you to cast a pointer to data to a pointer to function. The trick here is the workaround [suggested by POSIX for users of its equivalent to `GetProcAddress()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html). I think some people mentioned the first part above, but here's the second part :/ The OP's snippet uses `DWORD_PTR` instead of `void *`; I'm not sure if that's less safe... (They are the same size.)