# seg fault on coping std::string in std::vector<char> after pointer casting

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

Code below causes segmentation fault on **g++ 5.4.0 20160609**. But it works on **vs c++ 11.0**.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct fooStruct{
    std::string str;
    fooStruct() : str(std::string("")){}
};

int main()
{
    fooStruct fooObj;

    std::vector<char> cont(sizeof(fooStruct));
    std::cout<<"Size of string = "<<sizeof(std::string)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Size of vec = "<<cont.size()<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<sizeof(fooObj)<<std::endl;

    char* ptr = cont.data();
    ((fooStruct*)(ptr))[0] = fooObj;            //segmentation fault
    //((fooStruct*)(ptr))[0].str = fooObj.str; //segmentation fault

    std::cout<<((fooStruct*)(ptr))[0].str<<std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

The only difference between compilers is that msvc takes *40* bytes for string, while gcc only *32*. But i don't think that it does matter here.
Why does it work on msvc and does not work on g++?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I guess is why he's having a segmentation fault.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, sorry. I missed `[0]`, edited code.

Comment: Isn't `((fooStruct*)(ptr))[0] = fooObj;` just straight up violating strict aliasing and invoking UB?

Comment: Related probably : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446489/casting-a-pointer-does-not-produce-an-lvalue-why

Comment: why dont you use a way to copy the data that is less obfuscated and that works?

Comment: "It works" does not imply that it's not undefined, and it's undefined to assign to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: `((fooStruct*)(ptr))[0] = fooObj;` -- Remove the casts.  Now, what compiler error do you get?  Whatever it is, *pay attention to it* -- don't just shrug it off and tell the compiler to "shut up" by casting.

Comment: @Sklert -- If your comment on one of the answers is true and that you want to store any object in the vector, you could have used `std::vector<std::any>` or `std::vector<boost::any>`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior.  That means it could "work" or it could blow up, both are valid outcomes.

`ptr` points to a char array.  It does not represent a `fooStruct`.  So when you do

```
((fooStruct*)(ptr))[0]
```

You treat that memory as if it was a `fooStruct` even though it is not which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @juanchopanza Is it?  They did use `sizeof(fooStruct)` for the number of `char`'s.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. What's also wrong is the string copy.

Comment: Yeah.  I figured that was covered by my answer though since if `((fooStruct*)(ptr))[0]` is UB then `((fooStruct*)(ptr))[0].anything` is also UB.

Comment: It should be noted that even though the memory does not point to a `fooStruct`, it can be made to, by constructing a `fooStruct` object in that location first, via placement new. And then the dereference, as well as the assignment would be perfectly well defined behavior.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I was thinking that but couldn't that still be an issue as the char array doesn't have to be aligned to the structs alignment?

Comment: Thank you. But I guess it should work correctly if struct is POD. Correct me, if it is not true. The reason why it works on msvc is mb in different implementation of `std::string` not in UB.

Comment: @Sklert If the struct is a POD type then it is okay as long as the underlying array is properly aligned.  I'm not sure if it would be or not but I'm leaning towards it could not be.